# virtual directory asp redirector for php app necessary?

Tags: php, iis, virtual-directory

I created a virtual directory for my php app.

Now I get the "Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed."

Do I need to make some kind of dummy index.asp file that redirects (OR PREFERRED: just displays index.php)  or how to solve this?
I have restricted access to webserver, but index.php is set to be default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using IIS, you probably need to add index.php as a default index file.

1. Go to Start Menu -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools
   or possibly
   Start -> Control Panel -> Performance and Maintenance -> Administrative Tools
2. Double-click "Internet Information Services" or "IIS"
3. In the tree on the left, open up the folder for the web server computer, then locate the entry for the website you want to configure
4. Right-click that website and select "Properties"
5. Click the "Documents" tab
6. Make sure "Enable Default Document" is checked
7. Click "Add"
8. Enter index.php and click "OK"
9. Click "OK" again